# Guardar file en Javascript

Tags: javascript, archivo

Lo que necesito es poder guardar un archivo json en la misma carpeta del proyecto pero que se guarde automáticamente sin preguntar ubicación ni nada, cada x minutos.

El tiempo lo hago con **setInterval** pero no sé como guardar el archivo que genero.

Adjunto el código que tengo actualmente que genera un archivo JSON y muestra al usuario la pantalla para guardarlo en su PC. Pero lo que además quiero hacer es como un sistema de **backup**, que cada tanto tiempo se ejecute una función en segundo plano y genere ese mismo archivo pero que lo guarde en la misma carpeta del proyecto (va a estar en un servidor) sin consultarle al usuario.

Estoy trabajando en Javascript puro sin Framework

```
function download_data(){
    var arrayId = new Array();
    var arrayType = new Array();
    var arrayStruct = new Array();
    var arrayNombre = new Array();
    var arrayLat = new Array();
    var arrayLng = new Array();
    var arrayDesde = new Array();
    var arrayHasta = new Array();
    for (x = 0; x < objects.length; x++){
        var obj = objects [x][1];
        var tipo = obj.get("type");
        arrayId[x] = obj.get("id")
        if (tipo == 'point'){
            arrayType[x] = 'point';
            arrayStruct[x] = obj.get("struct");
            arrayNombre[x] = obj.get("title");
            arrayLat[x] = parseFloat(obj.get("lat"));
            arrayLng[x] = parseFloat(obj.get("lng"));
            console.log()
        }
        if (tipo == 'polyline'){
            arrayType[x] = 'polyline';
            arrayDesde[x] = obj.get("desde");
            arrayHasta[x] = obj.get("hasta");
            
        }
    }
    var list = [];
    //guardas los datos
    for (var i = 0; i < arrayId.length; i++) {
        list.push({
            "id": arrayId[i],
            "type": arrayType[i],
            "struct": arrayStruct[i],
            "nombre": arrayNombre[i],
            "lat": arrayLat[i],
            "lng": arrayLng[i],
            "desde": arrayDesde[i],
            "hasta": arrayHasta[i]
        });
    };

    json = JSON.stringify(list); // aqui tienes la lista de objetos en Json
    var obj = JSON.parse(json); //Parsea el Json al objeto anterior.
    download("data.json",json);
}


function download(filename, text) {
    var element = document.createElement('a');
    element.setAttribute('href', 'data:application/json;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent(text));
    element.setAttribute('download', filename);
    element.style.display = 'none';
    document.body.appendChild(element);
    element.click();
    document.body.removeChild(element);
  }
```

Comment: Por un tema de seguridad, no puedes saltarte el cuadro de diálogo de *guardar* en el navegador. Tampoco tienes acceso al sistema de archivos desde JavaScript ejecutado en un navegador web. Estoy asumiendo que el código que muestras se ejecuta en un navegador. Saludos

Comment: Debes usar la api file() y filereader() de js para enviar el archivo a un backend y luego recuperarlo desde el mismo. Como t dijeron no puedes grabar directamente a disco

Comment: Gracias a ambos por responder